# Resizing Image in react native without antialiasing

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to resize a pixelart image without react blurring it? [image]

Here's an example of what i mean, react native blurs the image for some reason and i dont see a way to turn this off

Answer (score -1):

You can use [resizeMode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) inside image tag.

e.g.

```
<Image resizeMode={"center"} source={{uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png'}}/>
```

Determines how to resize the image when the frame doesn't match the raw image dimensions. Defaults to cover.

- cover: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio)
  so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
- contain: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
  ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will
  be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view
  (minus padding).
- stretch: Scale width and height independently, This may change the aspect ratio of the src.
- repeat: Repeat the image to cover the frame of the view. The image will keep its size and aspect ratio unless it is larger than the view, in which case it will be scaled down uniformly so that it is contained in the view.
- center: Center the image in the view along both dimensions. If the
  image is larger than the view, scale it down uniformly so that it is
  contained in the view.

Comment: I don't want the image to stay the same height/width. I want it to be larger so i used stretch, but the problem is that stretching causes blurs

Comment: use a high-quality image for that and use above resizeMode

Comment: it would require resizing hundreds of art for my usecase. thanks anyway